# Phoenix fails to connect to Heroku's PostgreSQL server

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

This is the error I'm seeing on a virginal Phoenix app I've set up to mess around:

> [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.362.0>) failed to connect: **
>   (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28000 (invalid_authorization_specification): no
>   pg_hba.conf entry for host "24.25.201.68", user "koilqmnaakvfjg",
>   database "dc245o0vlbprf7", SSL off

Here is my `config/dev.exs`:

```
# Configure your database
config :hello, Hello.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "koilqmnaakvfjg",
  password: "somepass",
  database: "dc245o0vlbprf7",
  hostname: "ec2-54-243-54-6.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
  pool_size: 10
```

Something simple I'm missing?

Edit:

My pg_hba.conf file looks like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Comment: You should allow a connection from everywhere (or limit it to `24.25.201.68`) in your postgres config at `54.243.54.6`.

Comment: @mudasobwa See updated question w/ pg_hba.conf

Comment: A sledgehammer solution would be to put the line below somewhere in this file and restart postgres: `host  dc245o0vlbprf7  koilqmnaakvfjg 0.0.0.0/0 password`.

Comment: @mudasobwa That didn't work. What's the purpose of updating my local pg_hba if elixir is supposed to be reaching out to a remote server?

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the ssl parameter to true, and if the issue persists modify the pg_hba.conf file.

Solution:

```
# Configure your database
config :hello, Hello.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "koilqmnaakvfjg",
  password: "somepass",
  database: "dc245o0vlbprf7",
  hostname: "ec2-54-243-54-6.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
  pool_size: 10,
  ssl: true
```

Hope it helps :D

Update me on how it goes;

Good Luck;

Comment: No matter how I spun it, it didn't seem to work. It was resolved by not using Heroku's postgres service but substituting another one instead.

Comment: I'm using heroku service in my app no problems what so ever, after configuring pg_hba.conf. I'm glad you resolved your problem :D

Comment: No I don't, config looks like this and works perfect: 
config :test_rest, Test.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "someusername",
  password: "somepassword",
  database: "somedb",
  hostname: "ec2-46-137-109-220.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
  pool_size: 10,
  ssl: true

Comment: This fixed my issue. Heroku now require SSL when connecting to PostgreSQL https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2035